# Failed to bind the solution to SonarQube project, try again

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sonarqube, sonarlint

> See more information in the output window (SonarLint).

Note sure what the oupur window it is refering to. I get this issue in Visual Studio 2015 when binding a project to sonarqube

Failed to bind the solution to SonarQube project, try again.
See more information in the output window (SonarLint). Server side is at version 5.6.3 and was recently upgraded.

I've re-installed the plugin, tested on several workstations. No luck.

-- update : found this log
SonarQube request failed: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error). 
   Failed to download quality profile. Name: 'Sonar way', Key: 'cs-sonar-way-15069', Language: 'C#'

-- update #2
And I can confirm my quality profile is available - same ID
http://mysonarserver/profiles/show?key=cs-sonar-way-15069

here is my log on server side.

Fail to process request http://mysonarserver/api/qualityprofiles/export?name=Sonar+way&language=cs&exporterKey=roslyn-cs
java.lang.NullPointerException: null value

Comment: I am having this same issue with a fresh install of visual studio, sonarlint and sonarqube server.  
Binding solution to SonarQube project: Download quality profile(s):
SonarQube request failed: There is an error in XML document (232, 1). 
   Failed to download quality profile. Name: 'Sonar way', Key: 'cs-sonar-way-50377', Language: 'C#'

Comment: It also appears the XML is malformed:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RoslynExportProfile Version="1.0">
  <Configuration>
    <RuleSet Name="Rules for SonarQube" Description="This rule set was automatically generated from SonarQube." ToolsVersion="14.0">
      <Rules AnalyzerId="SonarAnalyzer.CSharp" RuleNamespace="SonarAnalyzer.CSharp">
        <Rule Id="S3869" Action="Warning" />
        [...]
      </Rules>
    </RuleSet>
    <AdditionalFiles>`

Answer (score 2):

[edit]
I have confirmed that 5.10.1.1411 resolves this issue. Thanks Amaury and Sonar Team!

https://sonarsource.bintray.com/Distribution/sonar-csharp-plugin/sonar-csharp-plugin-5.10.1.1411.jar

[original]

Rolling back to 5.9-RC1, https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-csharp/releases/tag/5.9-RC1,  manually seems to resolve the issue.

It seems the 5.10.0.1334 generates malformed XML for /api/qualityprofiles/export?exporterKey=sonarlint-vs-cs&language=cs&name=Sonar%20way

I have opened an issue on sonar-csharp's github. https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-csharp/issues/283

Comment: We fixed the issue by reverting the plugin indeed. thanks

Comment: Hi guys, just to let you know that the release of the bug fix will happen soon.